# phpbb 3 SQL delete user and all posts

Tags: mysql, sql, phpbb, phpbb3

I want to mass remove spam users from my forum's database.

If I have the UID of their account, what would be a good SQL query that I could script to delete that user and all their posts like the option in the ACP. SSH is much easier for me to login.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting users directly from the database is asking for trouble as it will leave all sorts of remnants in tables other than the user table.

Your best bet if you know user names/id's is to use the 'Prune users' function in the ACP under the 'Users and groups' tab.

Comment: What about when you have 500 internal server errors because the user has tens of thousands of posts? It seems to me that an SQL solution that can execute and clean up a user's mess is a really useful thing so we don't have to call from a web-served page

Comment: I had a similar problem deleting all posts by a user. There was a 500 internal server error. The user was deleted but all the posts were left. At first I thought I had to delete the user's thousands of topics manually, but found out you can just go into Forum in ACP and resynchronize each subforum.